# Serving static content from subdomain with codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, static, subdomain

I’m in the process of splitting resources across domains. I’ve read a few different ways on how to handle this. From what I’ve read the correct way to handle is to use absolute paths versus relative. If this is true, how would I handle this as I push my local development live? The domains won’t match from local to live.

The base_url allows for a single domain only as far as I’ve read. Should I create an asset path helper and autoload that? Or, is there something I’m missing here?

```
http://www.example.com would operate normally.
http://images.example.com/assets would point to my asset folder that exists in the root.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research this is the way I solved my problem. Thanks to the Codeigniter forum for helping me get to this solution. Create a switch that checks which stage of development the site is in and set the base_url and asset_url config accordingly.

```
switch(ENVIRONMENT)  //set in index.php
{
  case 'development':
    $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/';
    $config['asset_url'] = 'http://localhost/assets/';
    break;
  case 'production':
    $config['base_url'] = 'http://yoursite.com/';
    $config['asset_url'] = 'http://assets.yoursite.com/';
    break;
}
```

Then just extend the url_helper and create a function to get the asset_url

```
if ( ! function_exists('asset_url'))
{
    function asset_url($uri = '')
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        return $CI->config->item('asset_url') . ltrim($path, '/');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you're missing the part where the server configuration points stuff to certain places depending on the request that's made. This is before the request gets anywhere near codeigniter, so take a look at your server software manual and see what's up with that.

An example with Apache virtual hosts might be something like

```
#httpd.conf:
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName        example.com
        DocumentRoot      /var/www/http
        ErrorLog          /var/log/httpd/error_log
        TransferLog       /var/log/httpd/access_log
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName        images.example.com
        DocumentRoot      /var/www/http/assets
        ErrorLog          /var/log/httpd/error_log
        TransferLog       /var/log/httpd/access_log
</VirtualHost>
```

In this example, a request to `http://images.example.com/radical.gif` would look in `/var/www/assets/` for a gif called radical.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a constant in config/constants.php for your assets url and use it:

```
define('ASSETS_URL', 'http://images.example.com/assets/');
```

Then of course you would go for it like that:

```
<img src="'.ASSETS_URL.'image1.png" />
```